# How to hide passing value in links in cakephp 3.6.7?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Can anyone tell to hide passing values..

this li a link

```
echo $this->Html->link(__(‘Edit’, true), array(‘action’=>‘edit’, $loggeduser[‘id’])) ;
```

showing url is:

```
http://localhost/cakeapp/authexs/edit/83
```

I want to hide **83**, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide $loggeduser[‘id’] if you want to send it as a link. Instead of hiding you can encrypt it and then use it by decrypt the same in your edit action.

```
// Assuming key is stored somewhere it can be re-used for
// decryption later.
$key = 'wt1U5MACWJFTXGenFoZoiLwQGrLgdbHA';
$id = Security::encrypt($loggeduser[‘id’], $key);

echo $this->Html->link(__(‘Edit’, true), array(‘action’=>‘edit’, $id)) ;
```

and in your edit action

```
public function edit($id = null) {
 if ($id !=  null) { 
   $key = 'wt1U5MACWJFTXGenFoZoiLwQGrLgdbHA';
   $id = Security::decrypt($cipher, $key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1) You encrypt the ID as @Sehdev suggested - and then decrypt to obtain the ID in your code

2) Replace the link with a form containing a hidden input containing the ID of 83, which will submit a POST request to `/cakeapp/authexs/edit`. Then from within your edit action you can check for the presence of an ID field in the request data (refer to the [Cake2 Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) for reading request data from a controller)

The form may look something like this using Cakes Form Helper:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Authex', ['action' => 'edit']);
echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $loggeduser[‘id’]]);
echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
```

---

**Important Note**

I'm struggling to understand why you would want to hide the ID in an EDIT form. If you're concerned about users being able to guess another user ID then you have a major security flaw, as you should be implementing an authorization check at the controller level to prevent unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can get access to the `$loggeduser` data in the edit function itself, you can just not pass the ID at all in the URL, and instead get it from `$loggeduser` at that time. That is, your URL is `/authexs/edit`, and it will just always edit the current user. Of course, you can also allow an optional ID there and use `$loggeduser` only when that's null, to permit for admins editing other users. As @JoeRushton said, you'd need to be sure there's security checks on allowing this.